# How to get valid Credit Card number from GooglePay/ApplePay by NFC Reader?

Tags: java, nfc, credit-card, applepay, google-pay

I have a Spring Boot Application that read ID-Card (passport) and Credit Card. I have no problems with reading ID and plastic credit cards, but when I trying to read card from GooglePay (or ApplePay) I get virtual card nubmer, not original credit card number.

Example (original, from plastic card):

```json
{
    "cardNumber": "4149********3158"
}
```

Example (virtual, from GooglePay):

```json
{
    "cardNumber": "*4443********9065"
}
```

I have the same example with ApplePay. Instead of asterisks, the real card number is indicated.

Is it real to get original number? How to get credit card number?
I will add code samples if needed, but, in any case, I mostly use ready-made libraries.

Comment: Google Pay creates virtual card numbers for security purposes. It does not provide access to the real one. The number should still be "valid" per the luhn algorithm

Comment: Can i get original card number from virtual num?

Comment: No. That would defeat the purpose of having a virtual number at all

Comment: Ok, I know payment terminal that use NFC to scan card and show original card number. I can put plastic and get original num AND phone and get original num. A bit confusing...

Comment: UPD: I don't know, maybe this payment terminal "open and use" bank application and get number from it, not from GooglePay.

Comment: Virtual numbers are unique to payment apps, not to physical cards with NFC chips

Comment: @OneCricketeer, this terminal uses another application to read original card number! :) Thank you for help! Please, add an answer to this question, I'll mark it as Solved.